# From a MRI image in nifti format how to remove the skull

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have an MR brain image in NIFTI format. I want to remove the skull and extract the brain.I found an algorithm that says first we need to convert the image into binary image,create a mask and superimpose the mask on the input image to get the skull stripped image. But I do not understand how to get the binary image from the input image. I am using nibabel to access the NIFTI image.
Can someone help me on how to convert the input image into binary image?

This is the code i wrote and got the following outputs?Am I correct?
[image]

Comment: Can you give hints on how far you've progressed? So that we can actually assist you. This is not a place to get your homework done. 

Comment: There is a function in opencv cv2.cvtColor that can be used to convert an image into grayscale. Also the cv2.threshold can be used to apply otsu's method to threshold the image into a binary mask. But when i use cv2.cvtColor on the .nii image I get error. I suppose its because the .nii image is a 3d image. So how do I use these methods on the .nii image?